# Why should I connect the red/positive terminal first when jump starting?

Tags: battery, jump-start

So, it's fairly popular consensus online that it's red/positive clips to the positive/red posts, then the black/negative clip to the frame

One site mentions sparks, but you'll still get a spark when connecting black to frame. If positive is the potential shouldn't it be keep disconnected as long as possible?

Why do I connect the positive first?

Comment: I don't know the actual justification, but to me it makes sense to always attach positive first because it is easy to accidentally touch the lead to something else while installing. If the negative lead were already attached, then touching the positive lead to just about anything on the car that is metal would short out the battery.

Comment: @Paul ... please put that as the answer, *because you are spot on*. I almost wrote it out, then realized you'd already done it. This mainly applies to the second car being attached to the jumper cables. Once the first is attached and then if you had the negative attached first, touching the positive cable to any part of the ground would cause the short. There are a ***lot*** more ground points than there are positive battery points on a vehicle.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Maybe they should but fewer ground points on vehicles.

Comment: @nocomprende - Unless the car is completely made out of a non-conductive polymer, I'm thinking that really isn't an option. I believe even carbon fiber will conduct electricity.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I am thinking that if cars were made out of something really lightweight, like bubble wrap, they would be safer. Non-flammable, of course. The fuel economy would go up too. And, maybe the fuel should not be explosive. So much room for improvement...

Comment: @nocomprende - Sounds something like Demolition Man to me.

Comment: Once upon a time I had to jump start a car (back in the '60's). Problem was the guy had only one jumper cable. No problem 'cause cars then had metal bumpers. I just got close... attached the cable (which happened to be Black... designating "use it for the Negative side" to the Positive terminals. Then, drifted my car until it pushed solidly, bumper-to-bumper against the "Object" car. Started right up ;> )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Conventional lead acid batteries produce hydrogen gas as a byproduct of the charging process. This gas tends to collect in and around the battery. As you are aware making the final connection can generate a substantial spark. By making the frame connection the point where the spark occurs it is far enough from the hydrogen gas to avoid an explosion.

Comment: I wish I could find the studies, but the battery and battery charging manufacturers have demonstrated that the conditions required for a lead acid battery to create a concentration of >4% Hydrogen gas in the vicinity of the battery are so ridiculous as to almost never occur in practice. This was important in dealing with overzealous OSHA regulators who wanted to impose scientifically un-backed regulations everywhere a battery was being charged. I read the study when I was a member of the Battery Council International, but I can't find it on their site. Might be paywalled.

Comment: There are other flammable and explosive material around the engine.  If your spark did happen to create a small flame or explosion, you probably don't want this to occur near the battery.

Comment: @Paul Actual experience wins: seen a battery that had just come of charge, and was gassing, used to jump star a car : one spark and the resulting explosion caused 3 cars needing to be re-sprayed and the worker needed his eyes flushed very rapidly so he suffered no damage.

Comment: @SolarMike Since what you describe was not in a laboratory, it is impossible for me to believe you over the the various experts I dealt with while working in the lead acid battery manufacturing industry.

Comment: @Paul well, when it happens to you, you may believe me - as I said, 3 cars needed re-sprays and my colleague had acid in his eyes.. And you say "it was not done in a laboratory" - also if you know the definition of an "expert" ex = hasbeen , spurt...

Comment: @Paul really, if it was not an issue, why would there be **so** many warnings about sparks, naked lights and gassing batteries?

Comment: @SolarMike Please post when you can establish a causal relationship between charging and hydrogen gas concentration high enough to cause an explosion. Give the number of other causes of fires and explosions in a shop environment (including turning charging cables into plasma), I find no reason to conclude the cause was related to hydrogen outside of the battery.

Comment: This it’s fairly easy to achieve in my car, the jumper points are under the bonnet (hood) the battery’s in the boot (trunk) :)

Comment: My understanding is if you have to connect to the battery terminals then negative first and positive second since hydrogen gas came out of the negative terminal. However there are technically 6 negative terminals (5 of them are hidden) so the positive post may be closer to H2 source than it appears.  In addition the chasis jump point  is typically farther to the negative post than the apparent distance between positive and negative terminal anyway.

Answer (score 15):

I  don't know the actual justification, but to me it makes sense to always attach positive first because it is easy to accidentally touch the lead to something else while installing. If the negative lead were already attached, then touching the positive lead to just about anything on the car that is metal would short out the battery.

Comment: Can you explain how the opposite would not be true? eg, both positive connected and touching "just about anything" with the negative lead?

Comment: @QueueHammer The negative terminal of the battery is connected to the frame of the vehicle. Nearly every electrical component uses the frame as ground. Touching the negative lead to anything grounded will be the same, electrically, as touching the lead to the negative terminal (but note that not every component is capable of carrying the current required to start a vehicle).

Comment: It's a safety issue to avoid shorting the battery terminals through the frame. I was trying to determine if the voltage regulator might get fried if you connect the positive last, but that doesn't make sense because when you crank the car, you're applying the positive last. The grounds always have connection to the negative terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Simple, the car is always connected to the negative terminal of the attached battery meaning if you connect a charged battery's negative to amother car first, the whole car chassis will be connected to that charged battery's negative. This means that if you accidentally touch the positive terminal to any part of the car except the positive terminal, there's a high chance of a shirt circuit, arc and ultimately a weld, a second dead battery and possible burn marks on the person. Now vice versa, if you connect the positive terminal first, you can touch the negative terminal of the charged battery to any part of the "dead" car without shorting the charged battery. This is much safer.

Answer (score -2):

Positive has greatest potential. Connect negative fisrt, positive can arc and fuse. Connect positive first, negative having less potential won't arc. The higher the voltage, the greater the chance of arcing and fusion. 
On a car if negative first and you are touching any metal part of car, when attaching positive there is possibility of arcing through you. Your body becomes part of the circuit.
Think of positive like the Marines, first in, last out.
Be safe, don't die of stupidity.

Comment: Potential does not matter, it's potential _difference_, also called voltage. Connecting the first cable never causes a spark, since there is no return path for the current. With the second cable, one creates the return path, and it gives sparks - no matter which cable is connected first / last.